# How to find a nested property/value pair in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am coding a test script in Mocha. Here is the expected response:

```
"toplevel": [
    {
        name1: "value1",
        name2: "value2",
        ...
    }
    {
        name3: "value3",
        name4: "value4",
        ...
    }
    ...
]
```

Now I want to check if the response contains a member that has a specific property/value pair. For example, I want to check if in the "toplevel" array there is an element (which is an object) that contains the pair (name1: "value1"). How should I do it? Is there any Chai method to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method from the Array prototype to test if one item in an array matches a specific predicate:

```
if (data.toplevel.some(element => element.name1 === "value1")) {
  // chai assertions here
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems except using lambda function there is no chai api for this case.

Comment: I mean the methods like "nested" "include" "have" "members" or their combinations.